# Is it necessary to precede this verb with "to"?

Tags: prepositions, verbs

Example sentence:

> I had more important work to do: (to) think about how sell more bottles.

Is it necessary to add **to** in cases like these? Why or why not?

To my ears, the version without **to** sounds more natural. However, my brain tells me that it's more logical to add **to**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not truly idiomatic with or without **to**:

> I had more important work to do: (to) think about how to sell more bottles. <sup>no</sup>
>
> I had more important work to do: (to) contemplate how to sell more bottles. <sup>marginal</sup>

You would have to repeat "I had":

> I had more important work to do: I had to think about how to sell more bottles.
>
> I had more important work to do: I had to contemplate how to sell more bottles.

or change the sentence:

> I had more important work to do:  sell more bottles.

There is something about "(to) think about how to {verb phrase}..." and "(to) contemplate how to {verb phrase}" which makes them an imperfect mirror of *work to do*. Consider:

> I had more important work to do: wonder how we were ever going to get across that river.
>
> I had more important work to do: ponder how to cross that river.
>
> I had more important work to do: get across that river.
>
> I had more important work to do: cross that river.

Comment: You're right. I wonder why it's not grammatical to write: *I had more important work to do: **to** sell more bottles.*

Comment: The discord is semantic.   Syntactically it's a valid construction.

Comment: You could write *I had more important work to do, to sell more bottles* but then it's a case of ellipsis of *I had*, whereas with the unmarked infinitive it is a case of setting up a kind of apposition between *work to do* and the non-finite clause *sell more bottles*.  "I had more important work to do, *namely*, sell more bottles."